# encountering getting desired output

Tags: java

```
public class dog {
  String name;
  public void bark()
  {
  System.out.println(name+ "says warf!" );
  }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    dog dog1 = new dog();
    dog1.bark();
    dog1.name="bart";
    //creation of array
    dog[] dogs= new dog[3];
    //object reference
    dogs[0]= new dog();
    dogs[1]= new dog();
    dogs[2]= dog1;
    //Accessing object variables
    dogs[0].name= "fred";
    dogs[1].name= "marge";
    System.out.println("last dog's name is");
    System.out.println(dogs[2].name);
    //looping through array
    int x=0;
     while(x < (dogs.length));
     {
        dogs[x].bark();
        x=x+1;

     }
}
```

}

hello everybody....
i am new to java and been rookie in java programming....
in the abouve code....as per "head first java "textbook...
the output should be

```
"null says warf!
last dog's name is bart
fred says warf!
marge says warf!"
```

but in the above code as i coded it in eclipse ide.....first two lines of output m getting but not the last two....it seems that the while loop is not getting executed.....
can anybode tell me whats the problem with the code with reference to the output???

Answer (score 4):

You have a *semi-colon* at the end of the `while` statement:

```
while(x < (dogs.length));  // Remove the semi-colon
```

> it seems that the while loop is not getting executed.

In fact, it will execute infinitely, since the value of `x` is always the same, and you don't have any body of the while due to that *semi-colon*, to change it. The following code is just a local scoped block, unrelated to `while`.